# directionsService.route result get all markers latitude longitude values

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

[Sample displayed route on map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yQaD.png)

I am using directionsService on google maps. I am getting trouble on how to get latitude and longitude values of markers displayed on this route?

```
var request = {
                origin: nodes[0],
                destination: nodes[0],
                waypoints: waypts,
                optimizeWaypoints: true,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[$('#travel-type').val()],
                avoidHighways: parseInt($('#avoid-highways').val()) > 0 ? true : false,
                avoidTolls: false
            };
            markerID = true;

            directionsService.routes(request, function(response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                }
            });;
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: I dont get errors, Im just having a problem on how to fetch every marker latlng values on the directionsService displayed on my map. I tried `response.routes[index].overview_path` but it returns a lot of latlng values. I dont know where are the exact point of my markers along the route

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to loop through the legs array to get the data. For each waypoint an additional leg is created in the route. A route with no waypoints will have only 1 leg.

Each leg has a start location which is a latlng object. You can access each leg's coordinates like so:

```
for(var q = 0; q<route.legs.length; q++){
    alert(route.legs[q].start_location.lat() + " " + route.legs[q].start_location.lng()); 
}
```

The above code will give you the latlng coordinates for every marker except the destination. You can get the destination by looking at the end_locatoin of the last leg, but because the DirectionsService calculates directions between locations by using the nearest transportation option (usually a road) at the start and end points, end_location may be different than the provided destination of this leg if, for example, a road is not near the destination. That being said you could use the following code to get the end_location:

```
route.legs[route.legs.length-1].end_location.lat()
route.legs[route.legs.length-1].end_location.lng()
```

I hope this helps!